# qqplot versus histogram for lognormal distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, curve-fitting

I've got a dataset that's similar to lots of economic data: lognormal but with a longer right tail . . . or at least it looks that way in a qqplot

```
Temple.df <- read.delim("http://history.emory.edu/RAVINA/Stackoverflow/Temple.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

    ##generate theoretical quartiles
vec <- log10(Temple.df$total_land)
y <- quantile(vec[!is.na(vec)], c(0.25, 0.75))
x <- qnorm(c(0.25, 0.75))
slope <- diff(y)/diff(x)
int <- y[1L] - slope * x[1L]

tags <- c(-1,0,1,2,3,4)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Temple.df, aes(sample=vec)) + 
    geom_qq(geom = "point", distribution = stats::qnorm) + 
    geom_abline(intercept = int ,slope = slope) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=tags, labels=10^tags)
```

[image]

But when I try to overlay a curve on a histogram, the curve seems oddly shifted to the left.

```
ggplot(Temple.df, aes(total_land)) + 
    geom_histogram(color="white", aes(y = ..density..)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = "log") + 
stat_function(fun=dlnorm, 
  args=list(meanlog = mean(log(Temple.df$total_land)), 
  sdlog = sd(log(Temple.df$total_land))))
```

Is there a bug in my code? Why doesn't the density curve fit the histogram? What's my obvious STAT101 mistake?

[image]

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible by either including some data with `dput` or generating some data with eg  `exp(rnorm(100))`

Comment: @RichardTelford Does the read.delim command not work? I uploaded the data to that url

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that was a working link. Still better to make question self contained.

Comment: Yes, that's good advice . . . in the meantime, what's generating my weird curve?

Comment: I can replicate your result. Problem can be simplified to use meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1 which looks fine without the transform.  Suspect easiest solution is to log data and compare to `dnorm`